# Twitter share page does not open in an iframe

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm trying to open the Twitter share URL `http://twitter.com/share?url=http://google.com&text=Google` using Highslide iframe http://highslide.com/ref/hs.objectType

But the Highslide popup has no content!

Anybody knows what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Does no content mean its a white box?  Can you right click and open the iframe in a new window to check the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page has code specifically to prevent you from displaying it in a frame. The page is only made visible if it detects that it's not inside a frame.

So, you shouldn't put it in an iframe.

Comment: Is there a way to open it in an overlay instead of popup then?

Comment: @doublethink: It might be possible, but certainly not easily. You could request the document and incorporate part of it in the page, but it will be tricky change all URLs so that it loads the right images and posts to the correct page. The page is obviously not meant to be used in any other way than a stand-alone page, so you might have to respect that.